# Css pseudo classes input:not(disabled)not:[type="submit"]:focus

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I want to apply some css for inputs elements and I want to do that only for inputs that are not disabled and are not submit type, below css is not working, maybe if someone can explain me how this must be added .

```
input:not(disabled)not:[type="submit"]:focus{
box-shadow:0 0 2px 0 #0066FF;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 4px 0 #66A3FF;
}
```

Answer (score 418, accepted):

Instead of:

```
input:not(disabled)not:[type="submit"]:focus {}
```

Use:

```
input:not([disabled]):not([type="submit"]):focus {}
```

`disabled` is an attribute so it needs the brackets, and you seem to have mixed up/missing colons and parentheses on the `:not()` selector.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HSKPx/

One thing to note: I may be wrong, but I don't think `disabled` inputs can normally receive focus, so that part may be redundant.

Alternatively, use `:enabled`

```
input:enabled:not([type="submit"]):focus { /* styles here */ }
```

Again, I can't think of a case where disabled input can receive focus, so it seems unnecessary.

Comment: :not([disabled]) is a very verbose way of writing :enabled https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:enabled

Comment: @Adria did not work for me with <a> 's. Had one with <a disabled='disabled'> and had to specifically use the :disabled selector. FF65.

Comment: for some reason ":enabled" was not working in ie 11 for me

Comment: Is there any difference between using `:not([disabled])` VS. `:not(:disabled)` ?

Comment: There's no *maybe*. A `disabled` element cannot get a *focus* state. Neither via CSS or  JS.

Answer (score 23):

Your syntax is pretty screwy.

Change this:

```
input:not(disabled)not:[type="submit"]:focus{
```

to:

```
input:not(:disabled):not([type="submit"]):focus{
```

Seems that many people don't realize `:enabled` and `:disabled` are valid CSS selectors...

Comment: Why not shorten it further to `input:enabled:not([type="submit"]):focus{`?

Answer (score 9):

You have a few typos in your select. It should be: `input:not([disabled]):not([type="submit"]):focus`

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6u8yt/11/) for a proof of concept. On a sidenote, if I removed the "background-color" property, then the box shadow no longer works. Not sure why.