# nightwatchjs: using while loop gives "- process out of memory"

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am trying:

```
while(browser.assert.elementPresent("div[school-addlimit='2']>button[disabled='disabled']")!=null){
            createSchoolPage
                .click_add_button();
        }
```

if I use for loop without using condition, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post the HTML and the click_add_button function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`browser.assert.elementPresent` returns reference to `browser` object so you can chain your commands like

`browser.assert.elementPresent(".....")
              .click("......")
              .doAnotherAssertion("....")`

Because of that, your loop is infinitive

If you want to check if element presents on the page, and if so, then click on it, do it in that way:

`var selector = "div[school-addlimit='2']>button[disabled='disabled']";
browser.element('css selector', selector, function(response) {
    if (response.status !== -1) {
        createSchoolPage.click_add_button();
    }
})`

or

`var selector = "div[school-addlimit='2']>button[disabled='disabled']";
browser.waitForElementVisible(selector, defaultMaximumWaitTime, false, function(result) {
    if (result.value) {
        createSchoolPage.click_add_button();
    }
}`

## update

I see 3 possibilities when `element` is in DOM but it is `not clickable`:
* button is hovered by other element
* button is disabled
* button is in DOM but it is not visible

In first case, you may use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint to check if the button is on top

In second case, you need to update your css selector to find `element that is not disabled` (ex. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9207343/787828) (or find any element and then check their attributes)

In third case, use `browser.waitForElementVisible`

Comment: @nimus `response.status` appears always true because element is always available in dom. How to check something like `response.clickable`?
Thanks!!