# How to styling nth-last-child(3) if last-child not have class disabled in css ? or javascript

Tags: javascript, css, sass

i want style like this, but..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jISVR.png)

I stuck how to style nth-last-child(3) if last-child not have class "disabled"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0vZL.png)

My Scss:

```
.VuePagination__pagination-item{
        &:nth-last-child(3){
                &:before{
                    content:'..';
                    position:absolute;
                    right: 1px;
                    top: 7px;
                    font-size: 16px;
                }
        }        
 }
```

Html :

```
<div class="mb-5 mb-lg-0 VuePagination " id="pagination">
  <nav class="">
    <ul class="VuePagination__pagination">
      <li class="VuePagination__pagination-item 
       VuePagination__pagination-item-prev-page"> < </li>
      <li class="VuePagination__pagination-item 
       VuePagination__pagination-item-prev-chunk "> << </li>
      <li class="VuePagination__pagination-item"> 1 </li>
      <li class="VuePagination__pagination-item"> 2 </li>
      <li class="VuePagination__pagination-item"> 3 </li>
      <li class="VuePagination__pagination-item"> 4 </li>
      <li class="VuePagination__pagination-item"> 5 </li>
      <li class="VuePagination__pagination-item 
       VuePagination__pagination-item-next-page"> > </li>
      <li class="VuePagination__pagination-item 
       VuePagination__pagination-item-next-chunk disabled"> >> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not possible with CSS. You need JS.

Comment: Have you tried [css `:not()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Css pseudo classes input:not(disabled)not:\[type="submit"\]:focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207304/css-pseudo-classes-inputnotdisablednottype-submitfocus)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add meaningful descriptions to your images; don't just leave them as "enter image description here".

Answer (score 1):

Hi please do the following changes in your sass code

Your Code

```
.VuePagination__pagination-item{
        &:nth-last-child(3){
                &:before{
                    content:'..';
                    position:absolute;
                    right: 1px;
                    top: 7px;
                    font-size: 16px;
                }
        }        
 }
```

Changed to

```
.VuePagination__pagination-item{
        &:nth-last-child(3):not(.disabled){
                &:before{
                    content:'..';
                    position:absolute;
                    right: 1px;
                    top: 7px;
                    font-size: 16px;
                }
        }        
 }
```

---

You can use :not() css pseudo-class continue with :nth-last-child(3)

Example:

```
&:nth-last-child(3):not(.disabled){}
```

Learn more about [:not() css pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Working JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/katheer_mizal/qb4zwa1k/8/